# Integrating $\sin(n\theta(x))/\sin(\theta(x))$ for some function $\theta(x)$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, definite-integrals, harmonic-analysis

I have an indefinite integral of the form:

$$ \int \frac{\sin(n\theta(x)))}{\sin(\theta(x))} dx. $$

$\theta$ is a function of $x$ (and actually a complicated one).

Is it possible to integrate it --- analytically and/or numerically? The Dirichlet kernel for Fourier series makes me feel very optimistic about this one because they appear so similar. But I am not able to go too far with it.

What if the integral was a definite integral? like -- from $x = 0$ to $x = \pi/2$.

Comment: It's almost always possible to integrate a function numerically. Try the trapezium rule, or Simpson's rule.

Comment: Pretty general question ... Would try making $\theta$ the independent variable: $\int \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin\theta} \frac{dx}{d\theta} d\theta$   Also, any number of numerical schemes should work fine as long as $\theta$ is well behaved.  The only places to watch out for would be $\theta\rightarrow m\pi$, and then the value of your fraction would approach $n$.

Comment: Is $n$ an integer? If so, then this simplifies magnificently with a little complex analysis

Comment: yea, n is an integer, $\geq 0.$

Comment: i would be very, very interested in any simplication. My expression for $\theta$ is already something like $\cos^{-1}(****).$ A simplication would be immensely helpful!

Comment: When $n$ is an integer, $\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin\theta}$ is a polynomial in $\cos\theta$. i.e. $U_{n-1}(\cos\theta)$, the [Chebyshev polynomial of 2nd kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). Why you need to represent it as $\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin\theta}$???

Comment: @ achille hui: I am okey with writing it either ways --- as $ \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} $ or as $U_{n-1}(\cos\theta).$ The part that makes me get stuck is $\theta$ being a function of $x$ when the integration is w.r.t. $x.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, by Euler's formula, we have
$$
\sin(x)=\frac1{2i}\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)
$$
Substituting the above into the quotient, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}&=\frac{e^{in\theta}-e^{-in\theta}}{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}\\
&=\frac{\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^n-\left(e^{-i\theta}\right)^n}{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}
\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{n-1-2k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{i(n-1-2k)\theta}\\
&= 
\begin{cases}
1+2\sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2} \cos(2k\theta)
& n\text{ is odd}\\
2\sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \cos((2k-1)\theta)
& n\text{ is even}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
Whether or not this is in fact easier to integrate depends on your $\theta(x)$

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom: :) thanks ... I attempted using those identities (remembering it from some exercises on mathematical induction). But for me $\theta $ is a fairly complicated function of $x$ and, like you already observe, $\int \cos(**\theta(x))dx$ stays complicated.

Comment: Ah, sorry it wasn't so helpful in the end. In case you didn't realize, this amounts to the same thing as achille hui's comment. I suppose numerical integration is the way to go.